# Implementation of firing an object and removing him from the canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I spent a lot of time on this code. There is no success on it :( I have ship which is shooting. I have aliens which are moving towards ship! I wanna my bullets get one of the aliens and remove that alien from canvas (and gain and again until i remove all aliens). I thought about coordinates. I think that i have to compare coordinates of the bullet with coordinates of the alien. So if they are the same then just make alien of black colour which help me implement "disappear". However, I tried it. It did not work! Any ideas please?? Any help will appreciated. Thanks.

**JS**

```
    Alien.prototype.draw = function(context) {
        if(this.x == 0) {
            context.fillStyle = "red";
        } else if(this.x == 1) {
            context.fillStyle = "yellow";
        } else {
            context.fillStyle = "blue";
        }
        context.beginPath();
        context.fillRect(this.posx, this.posy, 20 , 20);
        context.fill();
    }

        var canvas = document.getElementById("screen");
        context = canvas.getContext("2d");

        if (canvas.getContext) {

            //init the aliens array
            var aliens = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                for(var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                    aliens.push(new Alien(j, i));
                }
            }
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="screen" width="300" height="500"/>
```

Comment: I'm seeing "Uncaught ReferenceError: shoot is not defined" in the console.

Comment: This question has been asked **twice** already [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21616453/remove-object-array-of-objects-from-canvas-by-firing-him) (incl. answer pointing you to the shoot() reference in setTimeout) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21594526/removing-object-from-the-canvas) (visible to 10k+ users only). Why not try to improve your question instead of re-posting it? There is a reason why you get down-votes and close requests. Please read the SO guide lines for asking questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I dont know it works for me @Xotic750

Comment: On this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/4X8xR/) I have ripped out all the unused code and cleaned it up, which includes the offending `shoot` code. Functions the same as your original otherwise. This could now be used to update and improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

As already answered in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21594526/removing-object-from-the-canvas) (now deleted) question:

You have an error in your `setTimeout()` call which causes the `shoot()` method to not invoke.

Don't use parenthesis as the function argument for `setTimeout` - this should only be a reference. When you use parenthesis you are actually executing the `shoot()` method and gives its result to `setTimeout()`.

Try this and it should probably get you further:

```
function shoot(){
    context.fillStyle = "black";
    context.fillRect(player.x, Y2--, 5,10);
    context.fillStyle = "red";
    context.fillRect(player.x, Y2, 5,10);
    if (Y2>=0) {
        timer=setTimeout(shoot, 1);    /// no parenthesis here
    }
    else {
        context.fillstyle="black";
        //  context.fillRect(X2, Y2, 5,10);
        Y2=320;
        // context.fillRect(X+23, Y2, 5,10);
    }
}
```

If this only solve your problem in part then please update your question with more information and details of what you try to achieve.

Comment: my question was how to delete aliens! Not how to shoot! I know that i needed to delete parenthesis! My issue is that I have no idea how remove aliens after bullet get them!!!!!@Ken

Comment: @ManuLakaster if you know that's an issue then fix the posted code so you don't lead us astray (or remove the part if not relevant)

Comment: @Ken, guess I was feeling generous today (weird), but I have cleaned up his code and created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/4X8xR/) for him. He now has every opportunity to improve his question and/or move himself on to collision detection.